Discussing religion in diversity statements for graduate school
A sample prompt for a US graduate school diversity statement is:

Describe how your character and experiences have formed you into someone who will contribute positively and effectively to not only the [department/school] but also to the field of physics as a whole. Highlight what is unique about you in a professional context and how you will advance a diverse, inclusive, and equitable environment within the department and the institution. Examples include explaining a meaningful teaching or mentorship experience you’ve had and what you learned from that experience or describing a social, educational, cultural, or economic obstacle you have overcome in your journey to get to where you are today.

From what I understand, the general premise is to talk about one's specific circumstances, even those derived from the circumstances of their birth (e.g., gender inequality in academia). In a similar vein, I was wondering if mentioning a religious identity is appropriate.
A student has turned to me for advice, but being unfamiliar with what role a diversity statement actually plays in admissions, I am quite ill qualified to offer any guidance.
They are legally categorised as an Indian Muslim. They have been actively inspired by the lack of representation that their specific community faces within academia (both at the national level and even somewhat at an international level) and the prevailing stereotypes/discrimination in their own country has played a role in their decision to seek a graduate school experience abroad.
As one might guess, the issue is that this specific religious identity is not seen in a good light everywhere. The student does not want to risk anything that might upset or cause issue with an admissions committee - but at the same time, diversity statements are mandatory in a lot of schools.

What is the point in mentioning "legally categorised"? Do they not identify with that religion, but are legally considered to be Muslim?

"From what I understand, the general premise is to talk about one's specific circumstances" - Eh, I would read some other Q&A here about these sorts of prompts and what they intend to evoke (though as with anything assessed by humans, the specific people reading the statement, who you do not know, will influence what is wanted).

@Dawn Yeah, the Statement of Purpose is separate (more focused on their achievements and their plans, research interests). This particular one is the diversity statement - its not required everywhere, but some of the schools they are targetting do require it.

@AzorAhai-him- Well, I am only sharing information I am absolutely sure of. I don't know what their personal beliefs are except that their legal religious identity is a Muslim (and they identify with it - at least culturally if not religiously; otherwise this question wouldn't arise).

Wow, I would really not want to be in a position of having to answer this kind of question.

In general, these types of statements can do three things:

explain challenges you have overcome that might be reflected as somewhat less desirable parts of your record.
to try to convince the committee that your background (or overcoming that background) has provided you with desirable personal characteristics like grit, curiosity, open-mindedness, good communication, etc.
to demonstrate to the committee that you  “get” diversity concerns and will be able to work well with people whose background is not like yours. For instance, you will be a good TA and not favor one group over another if placed in that role.

It seems to me that Indian Muslims are often somewhat of outsiders in their country and would provide an example that is useful. When you say it is perceived badly, I don’t think that would be the case in the US, unless the person said their background meant they would not work with opposite gender students or something really extreme. That would be a tricky one.

So, the idea is to show that they understand the concept of representation based on their lived experiences. I think, based on everything else, I would ask the student to highlight the fact that they understand the idea of diversity without focusing a lot on the exact details of their background. That seems to be a good balance to me.

I think a few details are a good thing. Describe an obstacle, being in a minority religion would be a good example. Explain what that has taught you.

Everybody can claim to understand something (and often believe that to be true), but that does not mean it is true. You often need to add details to support your argument that you understand.
